# Decorate autogenerated C# class (from proto file) and it's properties with attributes

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, protocol-buffers, sourcegenerators

I have some proto file (google protocol buffers).

```
message PersonDTO
{
   int32 id = 1;
   string name = 2;
   repeated AddressDTO addresses = 3;
}

message AddressDTO
{
   int32 id = 1;
   string fullAddress = 2;
   string city = 3;
}
```

I want to implement a server which receives from the client byte[] from RabbitMQ exchange which is serialized by using google protocol buffers.
The server deserialize this byte[] to the appropriate C# class PersonDTO which is autogenerated by grpc.tools nuget from my proto file.

I would like to use the same autogenerated class to work with Redis OM.
For using this C# class with Redis OM, the class's properties must be decorated with attributes like Indexed and Searchable according to https://redis.io/docs/clients/om-clients/stack-dotnet/

I wonder how i can use autogenerated C# class from proto file to work with Redis OM.
I got an idea to write some kind of source generator for this task. But i don't have an experience with it.
May be i understand wrong but source generator should generate a new file and i actually need to update the autogenerated file..

Will appreciate any good advises for how to start.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an alternative to annotations? Maybe some sort of fluent configuration?

Comment: From the attached link in my post, there is only one option as i can see.

Comment: If that is so, ... it's going to be dirty. You would either have to find a way to inject the annotation into the code generation process, or create a set of basically identical dtos you can annotate and map them, which is admittedly kind of ugly, too. _Or_ you ditch having the DTOs auto-generated by proto file and craft everything by hand, annotating for Redis and ProtoBuf... These are the options I would see off the bat. But maybe there is something better.

Comment: I thought about both of the options and none of them i like. The process should be automated without hand made changes. I thought about some file parser that just could insert rows with appropriate attributes when it recognize property and it's type... but taking in account that this is the autogenerated file from proto (it's not standart class definition) so it would be a challenge..

Comment: Might work with Rozlyn Tools though. But I am not sure about where to put that in the build process.